# How to use interpolation inside ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have states like this:

```
    .state('portfolio.work1', {        
        url: '/work1',
        templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/work1.html'                       
    })

    .state('portfolio.work2', {        
        url: '/work2',
        templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/work2.html'
    })
```

I want to set dynamic value of ui-sref like this:

```
<a ui-sref="{{ data.nextLink }}">
```

where `data.nextLink` is example '.work2'.

Interpolation not working with `ui-sref`. How can I do this?

Comment: Interpolation inside ui-sref works fine for me with ui-router 1.0.13.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function instead of `ui-sref`

```
<a href='#' ng-click='goToNextLink(data.nextLink)'>
```

and define `goToNextLink(...)` in the controller (you need to inject the dependencies on `$state` and `$scope`):

```
$scope.goToNextLink = function(link) {
    $state.go(link);
}
```

See the [documentation for $state](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).